# Secure erase hard drive

Tags: forensics, deletion, data-recovery

What device/method do you usually use to securely erase a hard drive?

The situation is, we have hard drives that we want to use somewhere else, and don't want any data to get recovered later,

I can use software secure eraser, but it may take some time since I have a lot of drives.

Do you guys have any experience using hdd eraser dock?

Comment: Need more info about the hardware. Are they HDDs, SSD? How old? Do they support the Secure Erase instruction? Basically, I think the manufacturer spec for your drives will be more useful than random internet people.

Answer (score 2):

Try the hardware based approach, such as [this one](https://www.startech.com/ca/HDD/Duplicators/usb-3-0-standalone-eraser-dock~SDOCK1EU3P). Those devices are not that expensive but solve the issue of reusing old HDDs and SSDs fast.

Answer (score 1):

Those docking device simply send a secure erase command to the disk. If you are looking for solution that will not cost you an arm and leg, you can look into how Linux send [ATA secure erase](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase), then get an eSATA external HD docking with multiple HD bay and send the command.